# PHPで打ち込んだセレクト項目がフォームに反映されない

Tags: javascript, php, html

PHP初心者です。sublimeTextを使用してフォームを作成しています。

元々構築してあったものを手探りで追加しているのですが、
`// セレクト項目設定` の箇所がフォームに反映されません。

確認画面を押すとエラー文字がでるページへ移行されますが、その時はフォームに反映され選択できるようになります。
（添付画像参照）

初歩的なご質問となり申し訳ございませんが何かコードが足りないでしょうか?
ご回答よろしくお願い致します。

※コードにならない部分は省略しております。

**発生している問題**
最初のページには選択項目が表示されない。(真っ白)
その後確認画面へを押すと文字が選択できるようになる。

---

以下PHP

```
protected $controller = 'Sample';
protected $formTemplateDirectory = 'Sample/';

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // POSTデータを取得
        $this->arrForm = $this->_objForm->getForm($_POST);
        $this->setFormItem();
        $this->setSelectItem();
        // ページ切り替え
        switch ($this->arrForm['mode']) {
            case 'confirm':
                // 確認画面
                $this->confirm();
                break;
            case 'complate':
                // 完了画面
                $this->complate();
                break;
            case 'back':
                // 確認画面から戻ってきた場合
                $this->getSessionData($this->arrForm['mode']);
                $this->_objPage->setAssign("key", $this->arrForm['key']);
                $this->_tpl = $this->formTemplateDirectory . $this->controller . "_input.tpl";
                break;
            default:
                $this->_tpl = $this->formTemplateDirectory . $this->controller . "_input.tpl";
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // 入力画面
        $this->index();
    }
    // フォームをSmartyにアサイン
    $this->_objPage->setAssign("arrForm", $this->arrForm);

}

// 入力画面
private function index () {
    // CSRFトークンをセットする
    $this->setCsrfToken();
    // 初期値を格納する
    $this->setDefaultData();
    $this->_tpl = $this->formTemplateDirectory . $this->controller . "_input.tpl";
}

// 確認画面
private function confirm () {
    // CSRFトークンをチェックする
    $this->checkCsrfToken($this->arrForm['key']);
    // エラーチェック
    $arrErr = $this->getErrCheck();
    if (count($arrErr) > 0) {
        // エラーあり
        $this->arrForm['mode'] = "confirm";
        $this->_tpl = $this->formTemplateDirectory . $this->controller . "_input.tpl";
        $this->_objPage->setAssign("arrErr", $arrErr);
    } else {
        // エラーなし
        // Sessionへ入力値を格納する
        $this->setSessionData();
        // 確認画面表示
        $this->arrForm['mode'] = "complate";
        $this->_tpl = $this->formTemplateDirectory . $this->controller . "_confirm.tpl";
    } 
}

// 完了画面
private function complate () {
    $error_flag = false;
    // CSRFトークンをチェックする
    $this->checkCsrfToken($this->arrForm['key']);
    // Sessionから入力値を取得する
    $this->getSessionData();
    // エラーチェック
    $arrErr = $this->getErrCheck();
    if (count($arrErr) > 0) {
        // 入力エラー
        $error_flag = true;
        $this->createLog('complate Function getErrCheck Error');
        $this->arrForm['mode'] = "confirm";
        $arrErr['complate_error'] = "validation";
        $this->_tpl = $this->formTemplateDirectory . $this->controller . "_input.tpl";
        $this->_objPage->setAssign("arrErr", $arrErr);
    } else {
        // エラーなし
        // contactdate 文字化け修正
        $contactdate = date('Y年n月j日 H時i分');
        $this->_objPage->setAssign("arrForm", $this->arrForm);
        $this->_objPage->setAssign("arrGenre", $this->_arrGenre);
        $this->_objPage->setAssign("contactdate", $contactdate);

        // 管理者宛てメール送信
        try {
            \Util::sendmail(
                \Service\Constans::$admin_mail_to[$this->controller],
                \Service\Constans::$admin_mail_cc[$this->controller],
                \Service\Constans::$admin_mail_bcc[$this->controller],
                \Service\Constans::$admin_mail_from_addr[$this->controller],
                \Service\Constans::$admin_mail_from_name[$this->controller],
                \Service\Constans::$admin_mail_title[$this->controller],
                $this->_objPage->getHtml($this->formTemplateDirectory . "mail/" . $this->controller . "_mail.tpl"),
                false // SMTP
            );
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // 送信エラー
            $error_flag = true;
            $this->createLog($ex);
            $this->createLog('complate Function sendmail admin Error');
            $arrErr['send'] = "送信に失敗しました。";
            $arrErr['complate_error'] = "sendmail";
            $this->_tpl = $this->formTemplateDirectory . $this->controller . "_input.tpl";
            $this->_objPage->setAssign("arrErr", $arrErr);
        }

        // ユーザー宛てメール送信
        try {
            \Util::sendmail(
                array($this->arrForm['mail'] => $this->arrForm['name']),
                null, // ユーザーメール CC
                null, // ユーザーメール BCC
                \Service\Constans::$customer_mail_from_addr[$this->controller],
                \Service\Constans::$customer_mail_from_name[$this->controller],
                \Service\Constans::$customer_mail_title[$this->controller],
                $this->_objPage->getHtml($this->formTemplateDirectory . "mail/" . $this->controller . "_mail_return.tpl"), 
                false // SMTP
            );
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // 送信エラー
            $error_flag = true;
            $this->createLog($ex);
            $this->createLog('complate Function sendmail customer Error');
            $arrErr['send'] = "送信に失敗しました。";
            $arrErr['complate_error'] = "sendmail";
            $this->_tpl = $this->formTemplateDirectory . $this->controller . "_input.tpl";
            $this->_objPage->setAssign("arrErr", $arrErr);
        }
    }

    if (!$error_flag) {
        // Session削除
        \Session::destroy('', true);
        // 完了画面へ遷移
        header("Location: thanks.html#thanks");
        exit();
    }
}

function getErrCheck() {
    $arrErr = $this->_objForm->getFormCheck($this->arrForm);



    return $arrErr;
}

// フォーム項目設定
function setFormItem() {
    $this->_objForm->addParam("type", "お問合せ内容", array("require"));
    $this->_objForm->addParam("name", "お名前", array("require"));
    $this->_objForm->addParam("tel", "電話番号", array("require"));
    $this->_objForm->addParam("mail", "メールアドレス", array("require", "mail"));
    $this->_objForm->addParam("contents", "お問い合わせ内容", array());
}

// セレクト項目設定
function setSelectItem($arrForm) {
    $arrItem = array();

    $arrItem["type"] = array(
            ""=>"お選び下さい",
            "選択項目1"=>"選択項目1",
            "選択項目2"=>"選択項目1",
            "選択項目3"=>"選択項目3"
    );
    // Smartyにアサイン
    $this->_objPage->setAssign("arrItem", $arrItem);
}


// フォーム画面設定
function getFormDisplay() {
    return $this->_objPage->getHtml($this->_tpl);
}

/*
 * 初期値を格納する
 */
function setDefaultData() {
    $this->arrForm = array(
        'type' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'tel' => '',
        'mail' => '',
        'contents' => '',
        // csrfのキーは格納しない
    );
}

/*
 * Sessionへ入力値を格納する
 */
function setSessionData() {
    \Session::set('type', $this->arrForm['type']);
    \Session::set('name', $this->arrForm['name']);
    \Session::set('tel', $this->arrForm['tel']);
    \Session::set('mail', $this->arrForm['mail']);
    \Session::set('contents', $this->arrForm['contents']);
    // csrfのキーは格納しない
}

/*
 * Sessionから入力値を取得する
 */
public function getSessionData() {
    $this->arrForm['type'] = \Session::get('type');
    $this->arrForm['name'] = \Session::get('name');
    $this->arrForm['tel'] = \Session::get('tel');
    $this->arrForm['mail'] = \Session::get('mail');
    $this->arrForm['contents'] = \Session::get('contents');
    $this->arrForm['key'] = \Session::get('key');
}
```

以下tpi

```
<form action="./#confirm" method="post" name="contact_confirm">
<dl>
<dt><label for="type">内容<span class="req">必須</span></label></dt>
<dd>
<select name="type" class="job_form" />
{html_options options=$arrItem.type selected=$arrForm.type}
</select>
<p class="error">{$arrErr['type']['error_message']}</p>
</dd>
    
<dt><label for="name">お名前<span class="req">必須</span></label></dt>
<dd><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="例：サンプル" value="{$arrForm['name']}">
{if isset($arrErr['name']['error_message']) }<p class="error">{$arrErr['name']['error_message']}</p>{/if}</dd>
<dt><label for="tel">電話番号<span class="req">必須</span></label></dt>
<dd><input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="例：000-000-0000" value="{$arrForm['tel']}">
{if isset($arrErr['tel']['error_message']) }<p class="error">{$arrErr['tel']['error_message']}</p>{/if}</dd>
<dt><label for="email">メールアドレス<span class="req">必須</span></label></dt>
<dd><input type="email" id="email" name="mail" placeholder="例：example" value="{$arrForm['mail']}">
{if isset($arrErr['mail']['error_message']) }<p class="error">{$arrErr['mail']['error_message']}</p>{/if}</dd>
<dt><label for="contents">お問合わせ内容</label></dt>
<dd><textarea name="contents" placeholder="例：〇月〇日" id="contents">{$arrForm['contents']}</textarea>{if isset($arrErr['contents']['error_message']) }<p class="error">{$arrErr['contents']['error_message']}</p>{/if}</dd>
</dl>
<div class="submit"><input value="入力内容のご確認へ" type="submit"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="key" name="key" value="{$key}" />
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="confirm" />
</form>
```

最初にサイトにアクセスしたとき(何も表示されない)

[image: 最初にサイトにアクセスしたとき(何も表示されない)]

その後入力内容の確認(画面移行後)
選択表示が出現して選択しメールが飛ぶようになる。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 最初のページが表示されるときのHTTPリクエストはPOSTですか？GETですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。最初のページ(選択項目がなし)はGET　エラーページ(選択項目あり)がPOSTでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSTメソッドの時にフォームに必要な項目を作成しているようです。
最初の画面表示がGETで来るということは項目作成ロジックが通っていないようです。

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {//POSTメソッドの時に
    // POSTデータを取得
    $this->arrForm = $this->_objForm->getForm($_POST);
    $this->setFormItem();//フォーム項目をセットする
    $this->setSelectItem();//セレクト項目をセットする
```

「入力」、「確認」、「完了」、「確認から戻ってきた」それぞれの画面でフォームが必要な画面で適切に処理を実行されるようにしましょう。

今回の場合は入力画面にでればいいのでindexを呼び出す部分だけでいいとは思います

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {//POSTメソッドの時に
    // POSTデータを取得
    $this->arrForm = $this->_objForm->getForm($_POST);
    $this->setFormItem();
    $this->setSelectItem();

//中略

} else {
    // 入力画面
    $this->setFormItem();
    $this->setSelectItem();
    $this->index();
}
```

しかし、これだとelse分岐の中で同じ処理を書いてしまっているので、
いっそ条件分岐の前にフォームのデータを作成する処理を書いてしまえばよいと思います。

```
$this->setFormItem();
$this->setSelectItem();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {//POSTメソッドの時に
    // POSTデータを取得
    $this->arrForm = $this->_objForm->getForm($_POST);

//中略

} else {
    // 入力画面
    $this->index();
}
```

Comment: ありがとうというコメントは不要です。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を参考にしてみてください